# $Re[f(z)]\le k Re[g(z)]$, $f,g$ entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $Re[f(z)]\le k Re[g(z)]$, $f,g$ entire function, we need to show $f(z)=ag(z)+b$, $a,b$ are complex constant.

My attempt: consider a function $F(z)=kf(z)-g(z)$ is analytic and $Real[F(z)]\ge 0$ so image of $F$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$ so $F$ must be constant so $kf+g=c$ so $f=ag+b$ for some suitable choice of constant. am i right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. Try $F(z)=f(z)-kg(z)$, so we have $\mathrm{Re}[F(z)]=\mathrm{Re}[f(z)]-k\mathrm{Re}[g(z)]\le 0$.